# How do I generate a random list more than once without using multiple if/else statements in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, while-loop

I am attempting to generate a list five times using only one while loop and only one list of numbers. I have written code that seems fine to me but the list is generating once and then it generates the same list for the other tests. I want a random list everytime. I do not know what is wrong so I don't know how to tackle it. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import random, time

number = 23
counter = 0
total = 5
counter2 = 0
current = 0
numbers = []
tally = 1
trash = []

while counter < total:
  while counter2 < number:
    for x in range(1):
      current = random.randint(1, 366)
      time.sleep(0.0001)
      counter2 += 1
      numbers.append(current)
  numbersS = set(numbers)
  size = len(numbersS)
  if size < number:
    print("1")
  else:
    print("0")
  counter += 1
  numbers = trash
```

Comment: Please disregard the tally variable it is useless and I forgot to remove it before asking the question.

Comment: So you want 5 lists? What are the size of the lists to be generated?

Comment: why not use `five_lists = [random.choices(range(1,366),k=23) for _ in range(5)]` to get 23 random numbers between 1 and 365 (inclusive) five times  at _once_?

Comment: @Jack, you can edit your question and remove `tally` yourself.

Comment: You might also want to look at [how to copy or clone a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) ... `numbers = trash` only relables the variablename `number` to point to `trash`'s data - it does not "copy" anything

Comment: `for x in range(1):` is wasteful as well ... you do not use `x` and range(1) only runs once so no need to loop at all...

Comment: @PatrickArtner random.choices worked. Thank you. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know what is wrong

The line `numbers = trash` is not doing what you want. Instead of emptying the list it will merely make `numbers` a synonym for `trash`. This means the next time you do `numbers.append(current)` you actually add that value to the `trash` list.

Look at this simplified code and comments:

```
trash = []
numbers = []

numbers.append(1) # adds to numbers, not to trash

numbers = trash # now both names are synonyms for the same list; currently empty

numbers.append(2) # adds to trash(!)

numbers = trash # this was already the case: does not do anything

print(numbers, trash) # [2] [2]
```

You should just do `numbers = []` instead of `numbers = trash`. Alternatively, you could stick with the same list and truncate it with `del numbers[:]` or `numbers.clear()`

Comment: This is very helpful. I don't know how I didn't see this solution. Thank you.